# Are the curvature Frank elastic constants of the liquid crystal the no-zero elements of the 6x6 elastic (stiffness) matrix?

Tags: elasticity, liquid-crystal

I was reading Landau's book on elasticity theory, and it raised this doubt.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have that book to hand, but I assume that the $6\times 6$ matrix you mention is the one appearing in solid state elasticity, with elements, in Voigt notation, $C_{11}\ldots C_{66}$, some of which vanish by symmetry.

No, they are not the same. They relate to different phases of matter: a solid, in the case of the $6\times 6$ stiffness tensor, and a nematic liquid crystal in the case of the Frank elastic constants. The liquid crystal is a liquid, in the sense that it has a viscous (not elastic) response to shear strains, as defined in terms of gradients of molecular positions. The only nonzero elements of the stiffness tensor are the ones associated with compression/expansion, as you would expect for a liquid (albeit with a reduced symmetry). These are not the Frank elastic constants.

The Frank constants refer specifically to gradients of the *director*, which characterizes the broken *orientational* symmetry of the phase. So it is related to molecular orientations, not positions. The formulation of this theory is different from the standard theory of elasticity in solids. Also, they have different dimensions and units: Frank elastic constants are measured in Newtons, whereas solid state elastic constants or stiffnesses are in Pascals.

The Frank (or better, Oseen-Frank) elastic constants, and their derivation, can be found in *The static and dynamic continuum theory of liquid crystals* by Iain Stewart, or in the standard work *The physics of liquid crystals* by Pierre-Gilles de Gennes and Jacques Prost. There's also a preprint of a chapter on this by Iain Stewart available at [Strathclyde University](https://strathprints.strath.ac.uk/50654/1/Stewart_Wiley_2015_Continuum_theory_for_liquid.pdf), as well as a brief summary on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_free_energy_density).

Comment: Thank you, @LonelyProf ! My question came from the article [https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.28.799] (Sound Velocity in a Nematic Liquid Crystal).  There the authors consider a liquid crystal as in the solid state.

And from the deduction in Stewart's book, it seems that the constants $k_{ij}$'s are generalizations of the simple elastic constant of elastic energy $E=\frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)^2$ and the force $\vec{F}=-k\Delta \vec{x}$

What do you think?

Comment: The elastic constants in that paper relate to (anisotropic) compressibility (see the second paragraph of my answer) which determines sound wave frequencies. They are *not* the Frank constants. The director only appears in that paper to define the unique direction. In fact, in their comment (ref 10) they state that "Relaxation of the director would appear not to be important" for the sound waves. As for your last comment, *all* (linear) elastic constants are defined by formulae resembling these. It does not follow that the elastic constants are the same, or even describe the same phenomena.